# SSH using Swift

Tags: swift, ssh

I want to connect to SSH using Swift language.
I have details of host, port, username and password.

Could you guide me an API to be used in Swift and the code snippet for the same?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Objective-C framework NMSSH
[NMSSH Github](https://github.com/NMSSH/NMSSH)

Or use my short version in Swift, that uses that library for connection, authentication, sending or executing commands

[Github link](https://github.com/BlindDev/PVPMikrotikSSH)

You can add that framework by using Podifle

```
pod 'PVPMikrotikSSH', :git => 'https://github.com/BlindDev/PVPMikrotikSSH.git'
```

Feel free to create any issues in the GitHub.

I haven't add any description on Git, because I made it only for my project, then  realised that it can be helpful for someone.

I will put the description on GitHb

And here is some short example

Basic - import the framework after pod installation:

```
import Foundation
import PVPMikrotikSSH

class SSHManager {
    
    private var pvpManager: PVPSSHManager
    static let defaultHost = "192.168.88.1"

    init(host: String, userName: String, password: String?) {
        
        pvpManager = PVPSSHManager(host: host, userName: userName, password: password)
    }
    
    convenience init() {
        self.init(host: SSHManager.defaultHost, userName: "admin", password: "")
    }
}
```

the to start the connection you can add more functions to that manager

```
func initiateConnection(completion: ((_ success: Bool) -> Void)?) {
        
        pvpManager.connectSessionAndAuthorize {(error) in
            
            if let sessionError = error {
                switch sessionError {
                case .noPassword:
                    print("Session not connected: No password")
                    
                    completion?(false)
                case .notConnected:
                    print("Session not connected")
                    
                    completion?(false)
                    
                case .notAuthorized:
                    print("Session not authorized")
                    
                    completion?(false)
                    
                default:
                    //there are few more types of errors just use them if you need
                    print("Session is not connected")
                    completion?(false)
                }
            }else{
                print("Session connected")
                completion?(true)
            }
        }
    }
```

to execute commands, you can add more function to that manager:

```
func execute(_ command: String, result: ((_ result: String?)-> Void)?) {
   pvpManager.executeCommand(command: command, completionHandler: { (error, result) in
                    
       //you can add error recognizer here        
       completion?(result)
   })
}
```

Comment: How to integrate the swift part you have shared. Could you let me know step wise as I am new to Swift

Comment: Thanks Woof... I used https://github.com/NMSSH/NMSSH and could solve the issue. will it be possible to execute command to fetch the values from database table

Comment: @RaghunathSahoo glad it helped. Executing command will return a string value from the end side, so you can try to send a json string from the server, then you can parse it.